# nmon NFS Performance Counters/Metrics

Tags: linux, nfs, performance-monitoring, nmon

I have recently used nmon to record NFS client performance data from a suse 10 SP4 host and now need help understanding what the captured read & write figures truly indicate.  With other performance measurement tools it was fairly obvious what the counters measured..  Writes(KB) = write throughput in KB or Read/Sec = read operations per second, etc.

nmon and other NFS tools simply label read activity as “read” so if anyone here can point me to a document/website or at least tell me your opinion on what the actual metric is for “access”, “read” and “write”.  I expect it is a simple point-in-time capture of read operations count, such as 100 reads processing at sampling time, but I do need to know for sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `nfsstat`? It seems to break down the activity type well...

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badclnt    badauth    xdrcall
944958162   0          0          0          0

Server nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink
0         0% 139832    0% 22081     0% 3129178   0% 353869    0% 0         0%
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod
765558883 81% 175500547 18% 37272     0% 11        0% 0         0% 0         0%
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus
33032     0% 1         0% 4084      0% 0         0% 0         0% 40464     0%
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit
165633    0% 9         0% 0         0% 0         0%
```